# Ubuntu 19.10 Top GNOME bar

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, 19.10, system-tray

I've been browsing but haven't been able to find anything related to this, I want to know if it's possible to make changes to the size and spacing between icons.

[image: Top bar image]

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for... this extension reduces the spacing between the icons: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/. See the extension website for configuration instructions.

Comment: [Unite extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) also reduces spacing and much more good things to make gnome usable.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the "Unite" extension fixed the issue!